# Multiple masked image

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am trying to make multiple masked images. 
How can I make;

1. `image_01 + mask_image_01 = image_02`
2. `image_02 + mask_image_02 = image_03`  ?

** `image_02` is result of `image_01` with `mask_image_01`.

(should be running on both Chrome and IE)

Comment: okay then how can you try? can you give sample code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I've understood you right, you can just use the `background` property for an image:

CSS:

```
#image_o1 {
    background: transparent url(http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/astrid_avatar.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="image_o1" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/linked/mask.png" />
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pb4tL/1/).

The only major problem with this method is that it uses the masking image in the `src` of the `img` element, and puts the 'real' image in the `background`.

If JavaScript is an option, then you could use the image you want to mask as the `src` of the image element(s), and then switch that for a mask, though this is a little messy (and could definitely be improved):

```
function imageMask(){
    var masked = document.getElementsByClassName('masked');
    var mD, mU, rImg;
    for (i=0; i<masked.length; i++){
        mD = window.getComputedStyle(masked[i],null).backgroundImage;
        mU = mD.substring(mD.indexOf('(')+1,mD.indexOf(')'));
        rImg = masked[i].src;

        masked[i].src = mU;
        /*
            For some (probably obvious) reason:

        masked[i].style.backgroundImage = rImg;

            refused to work, so I'm using 'setAttribute()' instead, in a
            hackish and hideous workaround.
        */
        masked[i].setAttribute('style','background-image: url(' + rImg + ');');

    }
};

window.onload = imageMask();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/pb4tL/3/)

Browser compatibility might be a problem with the JavaScript approach, though, as IE (I think) doesn't support either `.getElementsByClassName()` *or* `window.getComputedStyle()`. The majority of other browsers, though, seem happy enough with it. Tested in Firefox 7 and Chromium 14 on Ubuntu 11.04.